# Flooring prep for epoxy Pebblestone

Tags: flooring

I'm going to put in epoxy Pebblestone flooring in the basement.  My floor has the old 8x8 tiles.  They are all secure and have talked to people who say I can put the flooring over them.  Problem is I have a row of tiles which were loose and I have removed.  See the picture.  So do I just put a little more of the pebbles where these missing tiles are and ensure it is level?  Or should I put down some kind of underlay[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just cover the entire area without adding additional underlayment. I have had epoxy pebblestone resurfacing on several sidewalks and patios that had divots after they were done you could not see any variation because of the original surface. I doubt an indoor installation would be any different from outdoor.

Comment: Sounds like an old post, remove loose tiles and put new pebble cover down. Guess I did not read the answer I entered oops already hit enter.